# How to add new records to a field with @OneToOne in spring Data?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am making a jsf + spring application.
The database contains a table of games and it is displayed on one of the pages of the site.
Each game has a genre list and development status. These fields are annotated with @OneToMany and @OneToOne respectively and are also tables in the database.

But here's the question: How do I add new games now? How do I initialize these fields? Because the only way I see is to create a new genre for a new game every time. That is, even if game A and games B are of the same genre, then I have to create two different unique genres, not one.

And how to initialize these fields from JSF?
For example from the <p: selectOneMenu> tag

game.java

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "game")
public class Game
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "budget")
    private String budget;
    @Column(name = "profit")
    private  String profit;
    @Column(name = "number")
    private  String number;
    @OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "platform")
    private  Platform platform;
    @OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "status")
    private Status status;
    @Column(name = "start")
    private Date start;
    @Column(name = "end")
    private Date end;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "game_genre",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name= "game_id"),
               inverseJoinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name= "genre_id"))
    private List<Genre> listGenre;



    public void update(Game new_game)
    {
        this.name = new_game.name;
        this.budget = new_game.budget;
        this.profit = new_game.profit;
        this.number = new_game.number;

        this.platform = new_game.platform;
        this.status = new_game.status;
        this.start = new_game.start;
        this.end = new_game.end;
    }
}
```

development  status

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "status")
public class Status implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Название")
    private String Name;

    @Column(name = "Описание")
    private String description;
    public void update(Status new_game)
    {
        this.description = new_game.description;
        this.Name = new_game.Name;

    }
}
```

genre:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "genre")
public class Genre implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    public void update(Genre new_game)
    {
        this.name = new_game.name;
        this.description = new_game.description;

    }
}
```

Bean

```
@Component(value = "listgames")
@SessionScope
public class GamesView {

    @Autowired
    private GamesService gamesService;
    private Map<Long, Boolean> checked = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>();
    private List<Game> All_games = new ArrayList<Game>();
    private Game newGame=new Game();

    public Game getNewGame() {
        return newGame;
    }

    public void setNewGame(Game newGame) {
        this.newGame = newGame;
    }

    public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
          Game new_game=(Game)event.getObject();
          All_games.get(new_game.getId()-1).update(new_game);
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "INFO", "X/Y edit successful!");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
            int i=0;
            i++;

    }
    public void createNew() {

            gamesService.addBank(newGame);

            newGame = new Game();

    }

    public List<Game> getAll_games() {
        return gamesService.getAll();
    }

    public void setAll_games(List<Game> all_games) {
        All_games = all_games;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fetch the genres and development status from a dedicated repository, then on your object: .setGenres(retrievedGenres) and .setDevelopmentStatus(retrievedStatus). Then, persist your entity. Hibernate will handle the foreign keys for you

Comment: that is, I need to add another GenreService and StatusService to GamesView?

Comment: Add them directly to your GamesService, that would be better. Layers are allowed to communicate with other classes in the same layer or layers below - so a service can communicate with another service or layers below (eg Repositories). Then your GamesService will have a method which returns everything you need directly.

Comment: How do I initialize the fields from the JSF page?